# render method not working in Grails

Tags: grails

I just started with grails in action book.

made the new app by `grails create-app`

then the book says to have the following code in the QuoteController.groovy

```
class QuoteController {
    def index = {}
    def home = {
        render= "<h1>Real programmers do not each Quiche</h1>"
    }
}
```

Now when I browse to page http://localhost:8080/qotd/quote/home I get the following error:

```
Error 500: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: render for class: QuoteController
Servlet: grails
URI: /qotd/grails/quote/home.dispatch
Exception Message: No such property: render for class: QuoteController
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: render for class: QuoteController
Class: Unknown
At Line: [-1]
Code Snippet:
```

seems like 'render' is not a valid property?  Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?
I am using Grails 1.1.1

Answer (score 7):

....must be time for me to call it a night..book says to code the following:

```
class QuoteController {
    def index = {}
    def home = {
        render "<h1>Real programmers do not each Quiche</h1>"
    }
}
```

instead of render = "..."

Comment: hehe, classic mistake for beginner programmers =)

given groovy's dynamic nature, you need to watch out for typos all the time.

Comment: Small hint here, just so you know what's actually going on: render is a method with one string parameter (there are other overloads though). In Groovy you can omit the parentheses for methods with a single parameter.

Comment: Actually, to be a little more precise, in Groovy you can omit the parenthesis "if there is at least one parameter and there is no ambiguity".  See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Statements